# Evaluate UTF-8 literal escape sequences in a string in Python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have a string of the form:

```
s = '\\xe2\\x99\\xac'
```

I would like to convert this to the character ♬ by evaluating the escape sequence. However, everything I've tried either results in an error or prints out garbage. How can I force Python to convert the escape sequence into a literal unicode character?

What I've read elsewhere suggests that the following line of code should do what I want, but it results in a UnicodeEncodeError.

```
print(bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

I also tried the following, which has the same result:

```
import codecs
print(codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')(s)[0])
```

Both of these approaches produce the string 'â\x99¬', which print is subsequently unable to handle.

In case it makes any difference the string is being read in from a UTF-8 encoded file and will ultimately be output to a different UTF-8 encoded file after processing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`...decode('unicode-escape')` will give you string `'\xe2\x99\xac'`.

```
>>> s = '\\xe2\\x99\\xac'
>>> s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'â\x99¬'
>>> _ == '\xe2\x99\xac'
True
```

You need to decode it. But to decode it, encode it first with `latin1` (or `iso-8859-1`) to preserve the bytes.

```
>>> s = '\\xe2\\x99\\xac'
>>> s.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'♬'
```

Comment: Hey, this works fine for me in the console but I can't get it to work in my program (where I read in the text from a file).

Comment: @fallaciousreasoning, Could you post a question with reproducible example code?

Comment: Asked, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577801/how-do-i-convert-unicode-to-unicode-escaped-text

Comment: @fallaciousreasoning, I answered there. Check it out.

Comment: With the string 'To immunize or not to immunize, that is the question! An investigation into the reasons behind parents\\u27 decisions in immunizing their children against whooping cough in Western Australia', this is giving me the error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 102-105: truncated \uXXXX escape"