# How do I convert unicode to unicode-escaped text

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm loading a file with a bunch of unicode characters (e.g. `\xe9\x87\x8b`). I want to convert these characters to their escaped-unicode form (`\u91cb`) in Python. I've found a couple of similar questions here on StackOverflow including this one [Evaluate UTF-8 literal escape sequences in a string in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311277/evaluate-utf-8-literal-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python3/26311382?noredirect=1), which does almost exactly what I want, but I can't work out how to save the data.

For example:
Input file:

`\xe9\x87\x8b`

Python Script

```
file = open("input.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
encoded = text.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
file = open("output.txt", "w")
file.write(encoded) # fails with a unicode exception
file.close()
```

Output File (That I would like):

`\u91cb`

Comment: what is `print(open('input.txt', 'rb').read())`? Is it `b'\xe9\x87\x8b'` or `b'\\xe9\\x87\\x8b'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode it again with `unicode-escape` encoding.

```
>>> br'\xe9\x87\x8b'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'釋'
>>> _.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u91cb'
```

---

Code modified (used binary mode to reduce unnecessary encode/decodes)

```
with open("input.txt", "rb") as f:
    text = f.read().rstrip()  # rstrip to remove trailing spaces
decoded = text.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(decoded.encode('unicode-escape'))
```

http://asciinema.org/a/797ruy4u5gd1vsv8pplzlb6kq

Answer (score 3):

`\xe9\x87\x8b` is not a Unicode character. It looks like a *representation* of a bytestring that represents `釋` Unicode character encoded using utf-8 character encoding. `\u91cb` is a *representation* of `釋` character in Python source code (or in JSON format). Don't confuse the text representation and the character itself:

```
>>> b"\xe9\x87\x8b".decode('utf-8')
u'\u91cb' # repr()
>>> print(b"\xe9\x87\x8b".decode('utf-8'))
釋
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(b"\xe9\x87\x8b".decode('utf-8'))
'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-91CB'
```

To read text encoded as utf-8 from a file, specify the character encoding explicitly:

```
with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    unicode_text = file.read()
```

It is exactly the same for saving Unicode text to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(unicode_text)
```

If you omit the explicit `encoding` parameter then `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is used that may produce mojibake if it does not correspond to the actual character encoding used to save a file.

If your input file literally contains `\xe9` (4 characters) then you should fix whatever software generates it. If you need to use `'unicode-escape'`; something is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your input file is UTF-8 encoded so specify UTF-8 encoding when you open the file (Python3 is assumed as per your reference):

```
with open("input.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

`text` will contain the content of the file as a `str` (i.e. unicode string). Now you can write it in unicode escaped form directly to a file by specifying `encoding='unicode-escape'`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

The content of your file will now contain unicode-escaped literals:

```
$ cat output.txt
\u91cb
```