# How to decode this string? -> b'Katastr\\xc3\\xa1ln\\xc3\\xad mapa'

Tags: python, encode, python-3.7, utf

this string is html content `b'Katastr\\xc3\\xa1ln\\xc3\\xad mapa'`, that I need decode. I tried this `str(htmlContent).encode('utf-8')` but not succesfully.

```
str(htmlContent).encode('utf-8')
```

The result is still `b'Katastr\\xc3\\xa1ln\\xc3\\xad mapa'`

Comment: See [Evaluate UTF-8 literal escape sequences in a string in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311382/222914)

Answer (score 0):

You need decode:

```
>>> b'Katastr\xc3\xa1ln\xc3\xad mapa'.decode(‘utf-8’)
Katastrální mapa
```