# How to properly decode a utf-8 string with mixed-in octal escapes?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, escaping

When parsing `/proc/self/mountinfo` on Linux some fields of each line describing each a mount may very well contain utf-8 encoded characters. Since the line format of `mountinfo` separates fields by spaces, `mountinfo` escapes at least   (space) and `\` (backslash) as "\040" and "\134" (literally!). How can I convert a field value ("/tmp/a\ ", Python string `'/tmp/a\\134\\040'`) back into a non-escaped string?

Is there a better way than the following rather involved one (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311382)? That is, with less encoding/decoding chaining?

```
>>> s='/tmp/a\\134\\040'
>>> s.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'/tmp/a\\ '
```

PS: Don't ask why anyone sane would use such path names; this is just for illustrational purposes ;)

Comment: I don't think you can do better than that. I say be happy you don't have to use regex!

Comment: If it helps, you can omit the last argument `'utf8'` to the final `.decode()`, like you did for the first `.encode()`.